# Syncing Core Data with CloudKit publicCloudDatabase

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

How can I store/sync `core data` records with CloudKit's **publicCloudDatabase**?

Syncing works, but only with the privateCloudDatabase - which massively limits the use cases for combining `CloudKit` and `Core Data`. I hope I missed some fine tuning…

My aim: **entries** to the db **must be visible to all users** of my app/webservice (CloudKit JS).